# user input run time android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a simple converter code(convert feet to mtr) in Android. I am able to do this but only when user clicks some button. Now I want to modify it such that it starts to convert as and when the user gives input(Something like google converter). Is there any way to do this in Android?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: TextWatcher: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the listener to your edittext:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(addTextWatcher);
```

Add the TextWatcher interface:

```
private TextWatcher addTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int before, int count) {
        // here is where you could grab the contents of the edittext 
        // input each time a character is entered, and pass the value 
        // off to your unit conversion code. Careful to check for 
        // numerals/decimals only, or to set the proper inputType in 
        // your xml.
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence sequence, int start, int count, int after) { 

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable sequence) { 

    }
};
```